# Mod Rewrite problem

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a problem that I cannot wrap my head around.

I'm using Apache and PHP

I need to get:

http://localhost.com/cat_ap.php?nid=5964

from

http://localhost.com/cat_ap~nid~5964.htm

How do I go about changing that around?  I have done more simple mod rewrites but this is slightly more complicated.  Can anyone give me a leg up or point me in the right direction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^/cat_ap~nid~(.*)\.htm$ /cat_ap?nid=$1 [R]
```

The `[R]` at the end is optional. If you omit it, Apache won't redirect your users (it will still serve the correct page).

If the `nid` part is also a variable, you can try this:

```
RewriteRule ^/cat_ap~([^~]+)~(.*)\.htm$ /cat_ap?$1=$2 [R]
```

**EDIT:** As Ben Blank said in his comment, you might want to restrict the set of valid URLs. For example, you might want to make sure a nid exists, and that it's numerical:

```
RewriteRule ^/cat_ap~nid~([0-9]+)\.htm$ /cat_ap?nid=$1
```

or if the nid part is a variable, that it only consists of alphabetical characters:

```
RewriteRule ^/cat_ap~([A-Za-z]+)~([0-9]+)\.htm$ /cat_ap?$1=$2
```

Comment: You may wish to restrict which characters are matched (see the comments on kristina's answer). For example, if your IDs are always numeric, try using ([0-9]+) instead of (.*).

Comment: Yeah, I made the comment on kristina's answer. =) I thought about editing my answer, but the question doesn't state such a requirement. Either way, I'll edit my answer for the sake of reference.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the variable parts here are the "nid" and the 5964, you can do:

```
RewriteRule ^/cat_ap~(.+)~(.+).htm$ ^/cat_ap?$1=$2
```

The first "(.+)" matches "nid" and the second matches "5964".

Comment: I'm not sure that's gonna work, wouldn't it also match /cat_ap~nid~foo~5964.htm ?

Comment: I agree. The dots there should probably be negated character classes instead (e.g. [^~]).

Comment: You are both totally right, negated character classes would be much better.

Answer (score 0):

If you want everything arbitrary:

```
RewriteRule ^/(\w+)~(\w+)~(\w+)\.htm$ $1?$2=$3 [L]
```

Where `\w` is equal to `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. And if you want to use this rule in a .htaccess file, remove the leading `/` from the pattern.